# php-passing variable to popup window which code on the same page

Tags: php, mysql

Data will be load to the window and an ahref edit is able to click to pass the variable 'id' to popup window where the code is on the same page.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))                                    
{
$id=$row['file_id'];
echo '<span class=right><a href="#edit_form?id='.$id.'">[edit]</a> 
}

/* This is the pop up form code */

<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="edit_form"></a>
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("isiti");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_GET["id"])) 
{                           
    $id =$_GET["id"];
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publication where file_id='$id'");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$title=$row1['title'];
$author=$row1['author'];
$year=$row1['year'];
$abstract=$row1['abstract'];

if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
echo'<div class="popup">';
echo'<form method="POST" action="public_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">';                                              

echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="citation">Title</label>';                                                      echo'<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="title" id="title" value="'.$title.'">';
echo'</div>';
echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="citation">Author</label>';
echo'<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="author" id="author" value="'.$author.'">';
echo'</div>';
echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="citation">Year</label>';
echo'<input style="width:100%;" type="year" name="year" id="year" value="'.$year.'">';
echo'</div>';
echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="abstract">Abstract</label>';
echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="5000">'.$abstract.'</textarea>';
echo'</div>';
echo'<p>Rechoose your file here</p>';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">';
echo'<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">&nbsp;';
echo'<br/> ';
echo'<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" style="width: 150px">';
echo'<a class="close" href="#close"></a>';
echo'</form>';
echo'</div>';
}
```

The problem i faced is that it do not pass the right id. no matter what link i click it show the data from the first id.

Thanks for helping me .

Comment: Why are you having a `#` in your links : `<a href="#edit_form?id='.$id.'">` . May be give a try after removing the `#` .

Comment: It's because the last fetched row of data has the only value for your a href.

Comment: @Uours.. because after i click on this button it will display popup window... is without # it will show object not found ...

Comment: @LoganWayne.. so is there anyway to fix it ?

Comment: @ZKT Where is your $result before your first while loop?

Comment: @ZKT - can you post your whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This is now a single file:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))
{

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","isiti");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(empty($_GET['id'])){ /* IF EMPTY GET ID, FETCH LIST OF AVAILABLE FOR EDIT DATA */

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM publication");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))                                    
{
$id=$row['file_id'];
echo '<span class=right><a href="edit.php?id=$id">[edit]</a>'; /* CHANGED THE HREF */
}

} /* END IF EMPTY GET ID */

else { /* ELSE IF THERE'S AN ID TO GET */

$id=$_GET['id']; /* GET ID */ 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM publication where file_id='$id'");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$title=$row1['title'];
$author=$row1['author'];
$year=$row1['year'];
$abstract=$row1['abstract'];
}

echo'<div class="popup">';
echo'<form method="POST" action="public_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">';                                              

echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="citation">Title</label>';                                                      echo'<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="title" id="title" value="'.$title.'">';
echo'</div>';
echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="citation">Author</label>';
echo'<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="author" id="author" value="'.$author.'">';
echo'</div>';
echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="citation">Year</label>';
echo'<input style="width:100%;" type="year" name="year" id="year" value="'.$year.'">';
echo'</div>';
echo'<div>';
echo'<label for="abstract">Abstract</label>';
echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="5000">'.$abstract.'</textarea>';
echo'</div>';
echo'<p>Rechoose your file here</p>';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">';
echo'<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">&nbsp;';
echo'<br/> ';
echo'<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" style="width: 150px">';
echo'<a class="close" href="#close"></a>';
echo'</form>';
echo'</div>';

} /* END OF ELSE */

} /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY SESSION */
```

Your code is mixed with MySQL with MySQLi. I changed and turned it to MySQLi only.

Comment: u mean don do on the same page ... do on a new .php ?